# pass data in encrypt form using javascript and get in php

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I am working on a project in which user can search anything. I want to show search data in encrypt form in URL. I create a form and when user submit it I send user to result page, which I define in form action and form method is get.

```
<form is="search" action="example/search.php" method="get">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="key" id="header-search" />
<button class="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I need to show encrypt data in URL. If I encrypt data using java script then I can't get the data using PHP. How can I send data in encrypt form in URL and get in php in other page.

Comment: Isn't HTTPS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) is what you are looking for?

Comment: user enter any data to search but that data should show in encrypted form in URL and I can get all data using $_GET related to search. This search is used in header. so I can't send data to other page using php.

Comment: I recommend reading: [The Comprehensive Guide to URL Parameter Encryption in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are sending parameters in it so You can implement the process using **ajax**.
Before submitting form create an **ajax request** and send text field data in it. Use below variables for encryption

```
$cipher = "AES-128-CTR";
$key = "12345";
$opt = 0;
$iv_key = '123456789';
$iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
```

**encrypt** string using `openssl_encrypt function` and return as **ajax response**

```
$encryption = openssl_encrypt($string, $cipher, $key, $opt, $iv_key);
return $encryption;
```

Now store this string in a hidden field and send in form. On next page use the below code to `decrypt` the string and get data from **database**.

```
$decryption = openssl_decrypt($string, $cipher, $key, $opt, $iv_key);
```

make sure `$cipher, $key, $opt, $iv_key` should have same value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to url obfuscation?  If so, you can base64 encode the string client side, and decode it server side.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding for more details.

An example:

```
//client side
var encodedData = window.btoa("Hello, world"); // encode a string


//Server side (php)
$decodedData= base64_decode($encodedData)
```

Comment: I can encrypt data using atob(). but how I can I De-crypt  it in php. because I get all data from database according to the search

Comment: Just to remind anyone reading this, [base64 isn't encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).